# How to open Google Map in another tab with your coordinates in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have coordinates in a text box with a button. I am trying to take my coordinates from the text box and concatenate with the google maps. I do not want to show any map or something on my website. I just want to take my coordinates from the text box and open map in new tab with coordinates. My current logic:

```
var coordinates = $('#coordinates').val();
var url = "https://www.google.com.sa/maps/"+ coordinates +",12.21z?hl=en"

$("#map").on('click', function () {
        window.open(url, '_blank');
});
```

**Modification:**
I want to show something like this with marker:

[image]

and It showing this:[image]

Comment: what's not working with the above code?

Comment: The problem is its not showing marker in map?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var coordinates, url;

$("#map").on('click', function () {
  coordinates = $('#coordinates').val();
  url         = "https://www.google.com.sa/maps/search/"+ coordinates +",12.21z?hl=en";

  window.open(url, '_blank');
});
```

For zooming you need to play with these values:
[image][image]

Comment: So in search there will be my coordinates? Where I put my coordinates?

Comment: Perfect. But its too far how can I zoom in?

Comment: https://www.google.com.sa/maps/search/500,500/@40.4222637,-104.7257774,10.51z when you scroll you see the the last 2 values change, so I append those values to the URL.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand you?